# Reading custom firefox about:config

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I create new values on about:config of firefox and read them by programming language such as JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

var myBranchOfPrefs = Services.prefs.getBranch('extensions.myaddon.');

myBranchOfPrefs.setIntPref('somenumber', 456);

have to use setBoolPref or setStringPref depending on what you want value to be

this is very basic, usually you wont use it like this, youll set up a preference listener, so whenever its modified you update your addon with that value