# How to read firefox's about:config entries using Python?

Tags: firefox, python-3.x

How could I read [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) entries for firefox version 30.0 using Python ? I tried to use what is pointed by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834015/reading-custom-firefox-aboutconfig) (in JavaScript) but it did not help.

Comment: To clarify, you want to read if from plain python in a separate process, not stuff like `PyXPCOM` from within the Firefox process?

Comment: @nmaier I would love to read some entries in order to check their values. So my aim is a a list of couples (entry,value). of `about:config`

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: @nmaier Yes, my aim is to read it from plain Python, in a separate process.

Comment: I have create an autoit script to automatic export the configuration content and compare with python. Check the article and scripts from my blog http://www.shangerxin.com/?p=262
Although the solution is not pure python, but if you like you could use pywin to write some window API calls to replace the autoit script. It will works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a problem. Firefox comes with default values for most preferences, and only stores values different from the default in the profile. Added to this, each add-on may come with additional default values and create new preferences at runtime.

The default pref files might be contained within zip files, which complicates matters a little.

#### Files

Files you'd have to check for default preferences (in a standard Firefox distribution)

- `$APPDIR/omni.ja:greprefs.js`
- `$APPDIR/omni.ja:defaults/preferences/*.js`
- `$APPDIR/browser/omni.ja:greprefs.js`
- `$APPDIR/browser/omni.ja:defaults/preferences/*.js`
- `$PROFILE/extensions/*/defaults/preferences/*.js`
- `$PROFILE/extensions/*.xpi:defaults/preferences/*.js`

While preferences that were overridden from the default reside in `$PROFILE/prefs.js`.

So first you need to figure out `$APPDIR` (installation path of Firefox) and then `$PROFILE` (Firefox user profile path).

Then you need to read some files either in some directories (easy) or in some zip files (hard). A major problem is that you cannot just use `zipfile` to read `omni.ja` (and potentially some of the `xpi` files) because a typical python `zipfile` implementation is too rigid in the interpretation of the zip structure and fails to open these files. So you'd need your own `zipfile` implementation that can deal with this.

#### Format

In the `*.js` files there are essentially two types of lines (+ blank lines, comment lines):

```
pref("name", value)
user_pref("name", value)
```

The `pref` lines are default preferences, `user_pref` lines are user preferences (overridden from default).

#### Values

`value` is a Javascript expression such as `"abc"`, `true`, `1` or `2 * 3`. The latter is a problem, as you'd need a JS engine to properly evaluate it. But this isn't really a problem in practice, as you won't find expressions computing something in the wild (usually).

#### Conclusion

Really replicating the preferences system (or `about:config`) isn't an easy task and full of obstacles. It is probably far easier just reading user `pref.js` to see what's overridden and *knowing* the default values.

#### Example (just `prefs.js`)

```
import re
import json

PROFILE = "/path/to/firefox/profile"


def read_user_prefs(preffile):
    r = re.compile(r"\s*user_pref\(([\"'])(.+?)\1,\s*(.+?)\);")
    rv = {}
    for l in preffile:
        m = r.match(l)
        if not m:
            continue
        k, v = m.group(2), m.group(3)
        try:
            rv[k] = json.loads(v)
        except Exception as ex:
            print "failed to parse", k, v, ex
    return rv


with open("{}/prefs.js".format(PROFILE), "rb") as p:
    prefs = read_user_prefs(p)
    for k, v in prefs.items():
        print u"({type:<16}) {key}: {value}".format(
            key=k, value=v, type=str(type(v)))

    print
    print "Chrome debugging enabled:",
    print prefs.get("devtools.chrome.enabled", False)
    print "Last sync:",
    print prefs.get("services.sync.tabs.lastSync", 0.0)
    print "Pref that might not exist:",
    print prefs.get("does.not.exist", "default")
```

#### Alternatives

Write a [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) that [dumps interesting Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences) to a known file, or uses another form of IPC (sockets, whatever) to communicate with your python script.

Comment: You are an amazing man, @nmaier. I visited your profiles (website) and it is astonishing the number and quality of the tools you have developed. All my Respect for You, Great Man.

Comment: And thank you very much for all the details you gave me through your (very) generous answser.